# What the (f)lex rule for a regex?

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

I want to create a small language which allow entering regular expressions.  I will be scanning with (f)lex.

Therefore I need the Lex rule for a regular expression.  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Interesting question.  Any character can be part of a regex, so presumably you're looking for something more expressive than `.*`.  Since elements of a regex can nested more or less to an arbitrary depth, I suspect that parsing with a tool like yacc would be helpful to your project.  Since your regexes will be embedded in a little language, for lexing purposes maybe you will want to set them off with special delimiters, like Perl and JavaScript's backslashes.

Comment: What is a "lex rule for a regular expression"? That makes no sense.  A regular expression (in your language) is nothing that lex will recognize beyond a simple string literal constant. It would be impossible to define a lex rule for it. Any _surrounding_ stuff (markers, etc.) might be tokenizable, such as Perl's `s#regex#replace#flags`.

Comment: @DavidGorsline Interesting comment, thanks! Indeed regexs can't be specified by a lexer rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a "lex rule for a regular expression"? That makes no sense. A regular expression (in your language) is nothing that lex will recognize beyond a simple string literal constant. It would be impossible to define a lex rule for it. Any surrounding stuff (markers, etc.) might be tokenizable, such as Perl's s#regex#replace#flags

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Your answer made me take a step back from my deep coding; then I saw the obvious.  Thanks.